# Get all the unused variables in a Python project

Tags: python

How do I get all the unused variables and functions in my Python project?

Comment: Look into [Pylint](https://www.pylint.org/).

Comment: What IDE are you using for programming?

Comment: And/or a good IDE like PyCharm which will highlight unused variables while you code.

Comment: I am using wing IDE

Comment: @MatthiasBurger actually my organization has restricted the use of any other IDE, thats why

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/)!

Install it with

```
pip install pylint
```

And run it on your project files

```
find . -name "*.py" | xargs pylint
```

The above command will find all Python source files in your project and feed them using xargs to `pylint`. Pylint with output a report containing all lint warnings including unused variables.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I even explicitly added a global variable which I know is not used anywhere, and `pylint` didn't mention it.

Comment: @Hi-Angel perhaps the py file wasn't found?
Does it not work even with `pylint path/to/your/file.py` ?

Comment: It was found. When I pass the file alone to pylint, it only prints a `Missing module docstring (missing-module-docstring)`. As a matter of fact, if I create a file `test.py` with a single line `FOO_BAR = 'foo_bar'`, then run `pylint test.py`, I only get the warning about docstring. I thought, perhaps `pylint` generated bad ` ~/.pylintrc` file, and tried renaming it to ` ~/.pylintrcBCKP`, but it changed nothing. pylint version 2.6.0 here.

Answer (score 0):

Can use [vulture](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vulture/). These come in handy.It can't catch everything due to Python's dynamic nature, but can identify a lot without using the test suite completely.